# Can three vectors (one of them being a zero vector) form a basis for 3-dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Assuming that all three vectors are linearly independent, and one of them is a zero vector, can they form a basis for 3-dimensional space?

Comment: If one of them is the zero-vector then they are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 3):

The presence of zero vector in your set itself contradicts your statement.

Answer (score 1):

A basis Consists of linear Independent Elements .Which means  ifyou have 3 vectors and one of them is zero.Suppose that these three are independent  which means the equation $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3(0)=0$ Holds only when $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ but i can find $c_i$ not all zeros that this equation holds .Can you see it?